# Uncaught TypeError not a function - javascript class with prototyping

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am getting not a function error from javascript.

This is part of my object that I define:

```
Product.Config.prototype.configureSubscribe = function(funct)
{
    this.configureObservers.push(funct);
};
```

After that I create another object:

```
  Product.ConfigurableSwatches = Class.create();
    Product.ConfigurableSwatches.prototype = {
    initialize: function(productConfig, config) {
            // redefine some default options if configured
            if (config && typeof(config) == 'object') {
                this.setConfig(config);
            }
            this.productConfig = productConfig;
            // Store configurable attribute data
            var attributes = [];
            for (var i in productConfig.config.attributes) {
                attributes.push(productConfig.config.attributes[i]);
            }
            this.configurableAttributes = attributes;
            // Run it
            this.run();
            return this;
        },
    run: function() {
        // HERE IT BREAKS
        this.productConfig.configureSubscribe(this.onSelectChange.bind(this));
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.productConfig.configureSubscribe is not a function
```

Can someone advice what is the problem?

Comment: this.productConfig = new productConfig();

Comment: Only if the OP were not following regular case conventions in JavaScript.  Everywhere else, the OP seems to follow it though.  @bla009 where is the code that is calling `Product.ConfigurableSwatches.init`?

Comment: can you add some working code forking from your code.

Comment: @CodeiSir that initializer is missing. I added it before `Product.ConfigurableSwatches`. Can you add your answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `this.productConfig = productConfig` should be

```
this.productConfig = new productConfig()
```

to create a new Object with its prototypes